# How can I remove the tax line from my checkout?

Tags: css, templates, themes, shopify, checkout

I'm trying to get rid of the tax line altogether, or hide it from the checkout. I've tried everything I can think of to achieve this, but it's not working. Any suggestions?  Please help if you can, it's driving me crazy.

[image]

Here is the order template, and following that is the checkout.css

```
{% layout settings.customer_layout %}

<div class="section-title desktop-12 mobile-3">
  <h1>{{ 'customer.order.title' | t }} {{ order.name }}</h1>
</div>

<div id="customer-wrapper" class="desktop-12 mobile-3">


  {% if order.cancelled %}
  <div id="order_cancelled" class="flash notice">
    <h5 id="order_cancelled_title">{{ 'customer.order.cancelled' | t }} <span class="note">{{ order.cancelled_at | date: "%B %d, %Y %I:%M%p" }}</span></h5>
    <span class="note">{{ 'customer.order.cancelled_reason' | t: reason: order.cancel_reason }}</span>
  </div>
  {% endif %}

  <div class="note order_date">{{ 'customer.order.date' | t }} {{ order.created_at | date: "%B %d, %Y %I:%M%p" }}</div>

  <div id="order_address" class="group">

    <div id="order_payment" class="desktop-6 table-3 mobile-3">
      <h5 class="order_section_title">{{ 'customer.order.billing_address' | t }}</h5>
      <p><span class="note">{{ 'customer.order.payment_status' | t }}:</span> <span class="status_{{ order.financial_status }}">{{ order.financial_status_label }}</span></p>

      <div class="address note">
        <p>{{ order.billing_address.name }}</p>
        <p>{{ order.billing_address.company }}</p>
        <p>{{ order.billing_address.street }}</p>
        <p>{{ order.billing_address.city }}, {{ order.billing_address.province }}</p>
        <p>{{ order.billing_address.country }} {{ order.billing_address.zip }}</p>
        <p>{{ order.billing_address.phone }}</p>
      </div>

    </div>


    {% if order.shipping_address %}
    <div id="order_shipping" class="desktop-6 table-3 mobile-3">      
      <h5 class="order_section_title">{{ 'customer.order.shipping_address' | t }}</h5>
      <p><span class="note">{{ 'customer.order.fulfillment_status' | t }}:</span> <span class="status_{{ order.fulfillment_status }}">{{ order.fulfillment_status_label }}</span></p>

      <div class="address note">
        <p>{{ order.shipping_address.name }}</p>
        <p>{{ order.shipping_address.company }}</p>
        <p>{{ order.shipping_address.street }}</p>
        <p>{{ order.shipping_address.city }}, {{ order.shipping_address.province }}</p>
        <p>{{ order.shipping_address.country }} {{ order.shipping_address.zip }}</p>
        <p>{{ order.shipping_address.phone }}</p>
      </div>

    </div>
    {% endif %}

  </div>

  <table id="order_details">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>{{ 'customer.order.details.product' | t }}</th>
        <th>{{ 'customer.order.details.sku' | t }}</th>
        <th>{{ 'customer.order.details.price' | t }}</th>
        <th class="center">{{ 'customer.order.details.quantity' | t }}</th>
        <th class="center">{{ 'customer.order.details.total' | t }}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for line_item in order.line_items %}
      <tr id="{{ line_item.id }}" class="{% cycle 'odd', 'even' %}">
        <td class="product">
          {{ line_item.title | link_to: line_item.product.url }} 
          {% if line_item.fulfillment %}
          <div class="note">
            Fulfilled {{ line_item.fulfillment.created_at | date: "%b %d" }}
            {% if line_item.fulfillment.tracking_number %}
            <a href="{{ line_item.fulfillment.tracking_url }}">{{ line_item.fulfillment.tracking_company }} #{{ line_item.fulfillment.tracking_number}}</a>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
          {% endif %}
        </td>
        <td class="sku note">{{ line_item.sku }}</td>
        <td class="money">{{ line_item.price | money }}</td>
        <td class="qty center">{{ line_item.quantity }}</td>
        <td class="total money center">{{ line_item.quantity | times: line_item.price | money }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>  
    <tfoot>
      <tr class="order_summary note">
        <td class="label" colspan="4">{{ 'customer.order.details.subtotal' | t }}</td>
        <td class="total money center">{{ order.subtotal_price | money }}</td>
      </tr>   

      {% for discount in order.discounts %}
      <tr class="order_summary discount">
        <td class="label" colspan="4">{{ discount.code }} {{ 'customer.order.discount' | t }}</td>
        <td class="total money center">{{ discount.savings | money }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}

      {% for shipping_method in order.shipping_methods %}
      <tr class="order_summary note">
        <td class="label" colspan="4">{{ 'customer.order.shipping' | t }} ({{ shipping_method.title }}):</td>
        <td class="total money center">{{ shipping_method.price | money }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}

      {% for tax_line in order.tax_lines %}
      <tr class="order_summary note">
        <td class="label" colspan="4">{{ 'customer.order.tax' | t }} ({{ tax_line.title }} {{ tax_line.rate | times: 100 }}%):</td>
        <td class="total money center">{{ tax_line.price | money }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}    

      <tr class="order_summary order_total">
        <td class="label" colspan="4">{{ 'customer.order.details.total' | t }}:</td>
        <td class="total money center">{{ order.total_price | money }} {{ order.currency }}</td>
      </tr>   
    </tfoot>  
  </table>

</div>
```

Checkout.scss

```
/* Shopify New Responsive Checkout Styles - Epic Theme by Underground Media */

@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial|Glegoo|Droid+Sans|Lato:300,400|Arvo|Playfair+Display|Cutive+Mono|PT+Sans|Poiret+One|PT+Sans+Narrow|Quicksand|Noto+Serif|Lobster|Julius+Sans+One|Lobster+Two|Montserrat:400,700|Noticia+Text|Open+Sans|Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Oswald|Oxygen|Playball|Raleway|Roboto+Slab);



/* Body, Type, Headings & Links */  

body {
  color: {{ settings.text_color }};
  background: {{ settings.background }}{% if settings.bg != 'no_bg' %} url({{ 'background.jpg' | asset_url }}) {% endif %};
  {% if settings.bg != 'no_bg' %}  
  background-position: {{ settings.background-position }};
  background-repeat: {{ settings.background-repeat }}; 
  {% endif %}
  font-size: {{ settings.font-size }}; 
  font-family:{{ settings.font }};        
  line-height: 1.6em; 
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* Stops Mobile Safari from auto-adjusting font-sizes */
  margin: 0! important;
}


h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  color: {{ settings.header-color }};
  font-family:{{ settings.headings_font }};
  font-weight: {{ settings.heading-weight }};
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-top: 0;
  line-height: normal; 
}

h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a { font-weight: inherit; color: {{ settings.header-color }}! important; }
h1 { font-size: {{ settings.h1-size }}; }
h2 { font-size: {{ settings.h2-size }}; }
h3 { font-size: {{ settings.h3-size }}; }
h4 { font-size: {{ settings.h4-size }}; }
h5 { font-size: {{ settings.h5-size }}; }
h6 { font-size: {{ settings.h6-size }}; }


p { 
    font-size: {{ settings.font-size }}; 
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
    font-family:{{ settings.font }};
        color: {{ settings.text_color }};
}

p.strong { 
        color: {{ settings.text_color }};
}


/* Inputs */    

input[type="text"], input[type="tel"], input[type="email"], input[type="password"], select {
        font-family:{{ settings.font }};        
        background: transparent;
    color: {{ settings.text_color }};
}



/* Fieldsets, Fields */  

.fieldset {
    background: {{ settings.order-summary-background }};
        border: 1px solid {{ settings.dotted_color }};
}

.field+.field {
        border-top: 1px solid {{ settings.dotted_color }};
}


.field-group--has-subfields {
        border-color: {{ settings.dotted_color }};
        background-color: transparent;
}

.field--error { 
        background: transparent;
}



/* Header */

.header {
  background: transparent;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: {{ settings.nav_border_size }} solid {{ settings.nav_border_color }}; 
}

.header__backdrop {
  display: none;
}


/* Logo, Shop Name, Shop description */  

.shop {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.shop__name {
  text-align:{% if settings.logo_position == 'centered' %} center{% elsif settings.logo_position == 'inline' %}left{% endif %};
  font-weight: {{ settings.logo-weight }}; 
  line-height: {{ settings.nav-height }};
  color: {{ settings.logo_color }};
  padding: 0; 
  font-family: {{ settings.logo-font }}; 
  font-size: {{ settings.logo-size }}; 
  text-transform: {{ settings.logo-transform }};
}


.rgba .shop__desc {
    color: {{ settings.header-color }};
        font-size: {{ settings.h2-size }};
}      


.shop a {
    text-align: center;
}

img.shop__logo {
    margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Left Column */        

a.section__edit-link {
  font-size: 12px! important;
}


.payment-method {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius:3px;
  -moz-border-radius:3px;  
}

/* Order Summary */  }


.order-summary {
    border: 1px solid {{ settings.dotted_color }};
    border-top: 1px solid {{ settings.dotted_color }};
    background: {{ settings.order-summary-background }};
    color: {{ settings.text_color }};

}

.order-summary strong {
    color: {{ settings.text_color }};
}  

.product__info__name strong {
    color: {{ settings.text_color }};
}  

.summary-body, .order-summary__section { 
  border-top: 1px solid {{ settings.dotted_color }};
}

.payment-due__price {
        color: {{ settings.header-color }};
}

.footer {
          padding-bottom: 20px; 
          text-align: center;
}



/* Buttons */

.btn {
  background: {{ settings.button_color }}; 
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: {{ settings.button-weight }};
  font-family: {{ settings.font }}; 
  color: {{ settings.button_text }};  
  line-height: normal;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: background .5s ease,color .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: background .5s ease,color .5s ease;
  -o-transition: background .5s ease,color .5s ease;
  transition: background .5s ease,color .5s ease;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}


.btn:hover {
  color: {{ settings.button_text }};
  background: {{ settings.button_hover }};
}



@media all and (max-width: 600px) {

  .shop { padding: 0 1.5em; }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its depends, if you does't charge any Tax from the customers, then simply uncheck the tax checkbox from the product section in admin.  Then tax line does not visible on the checkout page

In the order template remove the Tax line items from order template here is code:

```
 {% for tax_line in order.tax_lines %}
      <tr class="order_summary note">
        <td class="label" colspan="4">{{ 'customer.order.tax' | t }} ({{ tax_line.title }} {{ tax_line.rate | times: 100 }}%):</td>
        <td class="total money center">{{ tax_line.price | money }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
```

Try this may this help this help you

Comment: Include the part of the code to be removed or your answer is more of a comment to the question.

Comment: What about the checkout page??

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can modify any part of the checkout process (not including the options found in Customize Theme) is by editing the checkout.liquid layout file, which you are only given access to if you have a Shopify Plus account. If you do have access to the checkout.liquid file, then you should be able to hide the tax line by adding:

```
.total-line--taxes { display: none; }
```

either in your header somewhere, or in your CSS file and then including that file in your checkout.liquid file.

Comment: I'm glad to see that there is a way to do it. I've just recently started messing with code, and I'm picking up on it, but I still may need it explained to me like I'm 5. Let me make sure we're on the same page though. I need to paste that code into the checkout.scss somewhere, and then reference that code in the template section of my .liquid that contains the code for the checkout page? Could the .liquid containing that be called customer/order?

Comment: First things first, I think you are getting the Order page and the Checkout page mixed up. The Order template file, found in templates/customers/order.liquid, is for displaying an order after it has been purchased. The Checkout template file, which is found in layout/checkout.liquid, and **only** if you are a Shopify Plus account holder, is what you are looking for. Do you have a Shopify Plus account?

Comment: I was getting the two confused. Since I do not yet have Shopify Plus, and I'm not able to see the checkout.liquid anywhere, I just assumed it was the order since it was the only liquid file that contained any of the language I was looking for. Thank you for clearing that up for me, the only way I'm going to be able to remove that line from checkout is to upgrade in the near future.